# dojo.getAttr is not a function

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am writing a dojo function with Dojo 1.6 that can modify attribute value:

```
    function replaceAttributeDojo(obj, attrName, newValue) {
        var value = dojo.getAttr(obj, attrName);
        if (value !== 'undefined') {
            //console.log('Found attribute '+attrName+' on object '+obj.attr('nodeName')+'[id='+obj.attr('id')+', name='+obj.attr('name')+', widgetid='+obj.attr('widgetid')+']');
            if (value == '') {
                //console.log('Attribute value is empty, removing the attribute');
                //obj.removeAttr(attrName);
                return;
            }
            var newAttrValue = value.replace(/[\d]+/g, newValue);
            dojo.setAttr(obj, attrName, newAttrValue);
        } else {
            //console.log('Did not find attribute '+attrName+' on object '+obj.attr('nodeName')+'[id='+obj.attr('id')+', name='+obj.attr('name')+', widgetid='+obj.attr('widgetid')+']');
        }
    }
```

Trace the code and find firebug lost on this line

```
var value = dojo.getAttr(obj, attrName);
```

And it telling me

```
dojo.getAttr is not a function
```

The function is defined outside dojo.ready, but is called inside of `dojo.ready()`.

Here is the section call the function inside dojo.ready()

```
dojo.query("div, input, select", row).forEach(function(){
    replaceAttributeDojo(row, 'id' , index);
    replaceAttributeDojo(row, 'name' , index);
    replaceAttributeDojo(row, 'widgetid' , index);
});
```

Everything on the same page inside `dojo.ready()` works fine, so how could this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If obj is a DOM node:

```
var val = dojo.attr(node, attrName); // getter

dojo.attr(node, attrName, newValue); // setter
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/attr.html

If obj is a Widget:

```
var val = widget.get(attrName); // getter

widget.set(attrName, newValue); // setter
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/_WidgetBase.html

Comment: Thank you that works ! Also an I ask whether we can retrieve Dom's id by `attr` function?